# What's a minimal set of generators of group $J^H \wr S_H$?

Tags: group-theory

For a group J and a finite set H, all the functions from H to J forms a new group $J^H$ in the natural way (i.e., for $f, g \in J^H, (f\cdot g)(h)=f(h)\cdot g(h), \forall h\in H$). Let $S$ be the symmetric group of $H$. The *Wreath Product* $$J\wr_H S$$ of $J$ and $S_H$ (with respect to set $H$) is defined to be the semi-direct product of $J^H$ and $S$ (with respect to the natural group action of $S$ on $J^H$). That is, for two elements $(f,\sigma),  (g,\tau)$ where $f, g\in J^H, \sigma, \tau \in S$, $$(f,\sigma)\cdot (g,\tau)=(f\cdot \sigma(g), \sigma\circ\tau)=(f\cdot (g\circ\sigma), \sigma\circ\tau)$$

Assume $H=\{1, 2,..., n\}$, and a minimal set of generators of $J$ are $a_1, a_2,..., a_m$. I want to know, at least how many elements in this group could generate all of them. Define $$f^j_i(x)=a_i$$

if $x=j$ and $f^j_i=0$ elsewhere.  Are {$(f^1_i, id_H)$, i=1,2,...,m, $(id_{J^H}, (12...n))$, $(id_{J^H}, (12))$} good enough to generate the whole group? It seems like the smallest generating set if it could.

Comment: Yes that set certainly generates the wreath product. But usually there will be smaller generating sets. For example $S_m \wr S_n$ is a $2$-geenrator group for all $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Wonderful, but really? I can't see it, or you know a theorem?